# Access this / vm instance from props default (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a plugin that sets some variables to vue's object prototype.

I need to access these variables from a prop's default property. How
can I achieve this?

Using the following example, webpack throws some undefined error.

```
//...
props: {
    size: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: this.$myPlugin.size
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `install` frunction of your plugin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Vue 2, you can specify the `default` as a function that returns the default value. That should have access to the current instance as `this`.

```js
props: {
    size: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default () {
            return this.$myPlugin.size
        } 
    }
}
```

The relevant line in the Vue source code is [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b7c2d9366cf731a1551286b8ac712e6e0905070e/src/core/util/props.js#L92) if you're curious. Note that the function is explicitly called with `vm` as its `this` value.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Complete answer. They call it with the vm scope.

Comment: Is this only working on plugin? I have tried on a child component props, it seems the vm(this) is not available and return undefined instead. -> Found the reason, because my props is also a function, vm is not available for props with type Function.

Comment: For reference, for event functions as props, may put `this` in parameter so that the context become instance proxy for using _self to access vue instance. eg. `this._self`